# How do we know that a function can be written as a power series?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

Most proofs of a Taylor series or a Maclaurin series assume that the function can be written as a power series. If a function can be written as a power series then:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}$$

But how can we know that a function can be written as a power series? For example, how can we prove that $\sin(x)$ can be written as a power series?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Comment: In short: you prove it from scratch, or show it is the case as a composition/combination of functions that can be. For instance, you could say "$\sin$ can be because $\exp$ can."

Comment: there is a difference between Taylor expansion and Taylor series : every $C^k$ function (and hence every $C^\infty$ funciton) has a Taylor expansion of order $k$ around a point, but only locally analytic functions have this Taylor expansion converge when $k \to \infty$, and only analytic functions are equal to their Taylor series in some disk around the point. there are many theorems for proving a function is analytic, but most of them require more complicated complex analysis facts.

Comment: Why the votes to close this question?  I think this is well proposed question and deserves to be answered.

Comment: Because that's what people usually do here when they don't know how to answer :q I've seen that many times...